# Splitting a JSON Array into POJOs stopped working in 2.16

Tags: apache-camel

I'm updating an old application that uses Apache Camel. The old code unmarshaled the input file containing a JSON array into an array of POJOs (Event), then split them to process each element in the array, like so:

```
GsonDataFormat eventFormat = new GsonDataFormat(new GsonBuilder().create(), Event[].class);
from("file:...")
.unmarshal(eventFormat);
.split(body(Event[].class))
...
```

This works fine up to version 2.15 of Apache Camel, but in v2.16 the code fails with a ClassNotFoundException for Event[] when I send a file through.

I can't find any documentation that explains why the change and how to correct it. Help?